# failure to create VPC in AWS due to invalid subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I'm using cloud formation to create a VPC. And it fails when it gets to creating the subnets. I checked and I believe the subnets to be valid. Though my networking knowledge is somewhat lacking.

This is the error I get:

```
00:46:49 UTC-0400   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Subnet    SubnetA The CIDR '172.16.64.0/16' is invalid.
```

00:46:49 UTC-0400   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::RouteTable    RouteTable  Resource creation Initiated
00:46:49 UTC-0400   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Subnet    SubnetB The CIDR '197.16.128.0/16' is invalid.

And this is the template I'm trying to use:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 172.16.0.0/18
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: JF-Staging-VPC
  InternetGateway:
     Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
     Properties:
       AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
       VpcId: !Ref VPC
       CidrBlock: 172.16.64.0/16
       MapPublicIpOnLaunch: False
  SubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        CidrBlock: 197.16.128.0/16
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: False
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGateway
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SecurityGroupSSH:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "SSH Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  SecurityGroupWeb:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Web Group"
      GroupDescription: "Web traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '443'
          ToPort: '443'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
Metadata:
  VPC:
    Description: "Creating the JF Staging VPC"
  InternetGateway:
    Description: "Creating an Internet Gateway"
```

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong and how to correct this?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with 197.16.128.0/16 which is a public IP address which cannot be assigned to a VPC or a subnet.

I think that you really meant to use the address:

172.16.128.0/16

[EDIT]

Change your VPC to 172.16.0.0/16
Then change each subnet to use a portion of the /16 e.g. /24
Examples:

172.16.0.0/24

172.16.1.0/24

172.16.2.0/24

etc.

The issue with your current implementation is that your VPC is /18 which is smaller than the subnets that you are trying to create /16. You want the reverse, /16 for the VPC and /24 or anything smaller than /16 for the subnets.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I switched to the subnet you suggest and now I get this error:
 `The CIDR '172.16.128.0/16' conflicts with another subnet`
Everything else in the template stays the same

Comment: @bluethundr. I updated my answer after re-reading your template. Also review John Rotenstein answer.

Answer (score 4):

As per the error message, your IP address (CIDR) ranges are invalid.

It sets the following CIDR ranges:

- VPC: 172.16.0.0/18
- SubnetA: 172.16.64.0/16
- SubnetB: 197.16.128.0/16

Neither of these subnet ranges is part of the VPC range. All subnet ranges must fall within the range specified by the VPC. In fact, both of your subnets are *larger* (/16) than the VPC (/18).

Here, for example, are ranges that work fine:

- VPC: 172.16.0.0/16
- SubnetA: 172.16.64.0/24
- SubnetB: 172.16.128.0/24

If you do not understand CIDR ranges, see: [Understanding IP Addresses, Subnets, and CIDR Notation for Networking](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-ip-addresses-subnets-and-cidr-notation-for-networking)